# Elastic Transcoder Job Status in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, status, amazon-elastic-transcoder

How do you print the Job status of an elastic transcoder job with the following parameters in php

> {Progressing, Completed, Warning, Error}

I have submitted the job and the video is transcoding. I'm retrieving the completed videos list through S3 Listing.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: I need to get the status of the job while its transcoding and after transcoding.I don't know how to retrieve the error status and progressing status.

Answer (score 0):

Provided with `jobId`, you can query job status and print whatever you want:

```
$createResult = $transcoder->createJob($jobData);
$jobId = $createResult->get('Job')['Id'];

$readResult = $transcoder->readJob(['Id' => $jobId]);
$readResult->get('Job')['Status'];
```